# Replace in Polars df

Tags: python, python-polars

I am new to using Polars. How can i change every X that is in a cell to a 1.
For example:

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ X   ┆ null│
│ null┆ X   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Should be:

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 0   │
│ 0   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

There are also other columnes that i dont want to change.
What i have right now:

```
# what to change to what
mapper = {
    "X": 1,
    null: 0,

}
# columne name list
columnes = pdf.columns
# change it
for x in columnes:
    pdf = pdf.select(pl.all().map_dict(mapper, default=pl.col(x)))
```

Where is my mistake and how to change it in order for it to work?
I tried to just use .replace but it seems that with this function you can only replace whole columnes and not only particular values.

Comment: Please update your question with sample `df` and expected outcome, so that the readers can easily work on it.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I updated it according to your recommandation

Comment: Your df does not seems to a valid one. What is `X`? What is the column dtype?

Comment: same comment as @AbdulNiyasPM. If A and B are integer columns, what is X? is it an integer? is it the string "X" (in that case the full column will be a string)?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM I updated the question, sry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

The first odd thing is that you seem to have strings (ie. X) mixed with numbers where neither is quoted so I'm not sure if by X you mean a different number.

Assuming they should be quoted and you mean a literal X then that means the rest of the values ought to be strings too like this:

Note: the question was recently changed. I'm answering the version that had

```
pdf=pl.DataFrame({'A': ['X', '2'], 'B': ['3', 'X']})

mapper = {
"X": 1,
}
```

With these, you're going to have an issue where you can't have strings and integers mixed which is what map_dict with your mapper would do. To get around that you can use a non-strict cast and a coalesce like this:

```
pdf.with_columns(
    pl.coalesce(
        pl.col(col_name).cast(pl.Int64(), strict=False), 
        pl.col(col_name).map_dict(mapper)) 
    for col_name in pdf.columns)
```

The way this works is that `coalesce` takes any number of expressions and returns the first one which is not null. The first argument is just a cast to Ints with `strict=False` so that it returns nulls instead of producing an error. In the case of 'X' it will return null which makes `coalesce` look to the next argument which is the `map_dict` converting the 'X' into a 1. We put the for loop in the `with_columns` context as a generator since `coalesce` seemingly can't deal with `pl.all`.

Result:

```
shape: (2, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 3   │
│ 2   ┆ 1   │
└─────┴─────┘
```

Bonus answer, for the edit.

with

```
pdf=pl.DataFrame({'A': ['X', None], 'B': [None, 'X']})

mapper = {
"X": 1,
None: 0
}
```

you can't `map_dict` on a key of None, I think, because there's a disconnect between a python None and a polars null.

You can, instead, do

```
pdf.with_columns(
    pl.coalesce(
        pl.col(col_name).fill_null(mapper[None]).cast(pl.Int64(), strict=False), 
        pl.col(col_name).map_dict(mapper)) 
    for col_name in pdf.columns)
```

Comment: I updated my question. I confused some things. I am not sure if your answer still fits.

Answer (score 0):

[`Expr.replace`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.replace.html) has since been added.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame({
   "A": ["X", None, "Y"],
   "B": [None, "X", "Y"],
   "C": ["X", None, "Y"],
   "D": ["A", "B",  "C"]
})
```

`return_dtype=` can be specified to set the type before filling in the nulls with integer `0`

```py
df.with_columns(
   pl.col("A", "B").replace("X", "10", return_dtype=pl.Int64)
     .fill_null(0)
)
```

```py
shape: (3, 4)
┌─────┬─────┬──────┬─────┐
│ A   ┆ B   ┆ C    ┆ D   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ ---  ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ str  ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╪══════╪═════╡
│ 10  ┆ 0   ┆ X    ┆ A   │
│ 0   ┆ 10  ┆ null ┆ B   │
│ 0   ┆ 0   ┆ Y    ┆ C   │
└─────┴─────┴──────┴─────┘
```

Comment: But my Problem is that the columnes datatype is a str but i want it to change to int.

Comment: @Manuel You can `.cast()` as others have shown?

Comment: @jquerious if i do: cols = pdf.columns

pdf.with_columns(
    pl.coalesce(
        pl.col(col_name).fill_null(mapper[None]).cast(pl.Int64(), strict=False), 
        pl.col(col_name).map_dict(mapper)) 
    for col_name in pdf.columns) then: ComputeError: ValueError: Remapping keys for map_dict could not be converted to Int64: found Utf8

Comment: @Manuel If using `.fill_null`, you want to have that step last, after casting. I've edited the answer.